# Linux server: disk capacity expansion

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am new to Linux, and I happened to tackle this problem: expand disk size on the data server.

I have upgraded 6 data disks of the Ubuntu server for capacity expansion (/dev/sdb), but I am not sure how to make the server recognize the new volumes.

Tried several commands below that I could find online, and reboot did not help.

**Is there any precise command to expand those disk size?**

```
df -h

Filesystem        Size        Used        Avail        Use%        Mounted on
udev               32G        4.0K          32G          1%             /dev
tmpfs             6.3G        2.1M         6.3G          1%             /run
/dev/sda1         212G        8.7G         192G          5%             /
none              4.0K           0         4.0K          0%             /sys/fs/cgroup
none              5.0M           0         5.0M          0%             /run/lock
none               32G         45M          32G          1%             /run/shm
none              100M         44K         100M          1%             /run/user
/dev/sdb          2.7T        2.6T         5.0G        100%             /home2
```

```
lsblk

NAME        MAJ:MIN        RM        SIZE        RO    TYPE    MOUNTPOINT
sda           8:0           0      278.9G         0    disk
- sda1        8:1           0      214.9G         0    part    /
- sda2        8:2           0          1K         0    part
- sda5        8:5           0         64G         0    part    [SWAP]
sdb           8:16          0        2.7T         0    disk    /home2
sr0          11:0           1       1024M         0    rom
```

**Tried several commands like:**

```
~$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

```
~$ growpart /dev/sdb 2
FAILED: unable to determine partition type
```

```
~$ sudo resize2fs /dev/sdb
The filesystem is already 731873280 blocks long. Nothing to do!
```

Comment: What new disks? Exactly what did you do? What is the hardware?

Comment: A few things of note: There is no partition table on `/dev/sdb`, the entire volume is formatted with a filesystem. This is fine, but DO NOT attempt to put a partition table on that device - doing so will damage the filesystem on it. You have not mentioned how `/dev/sdb` came to be - is it a RAID array? A virtual disk from a hypervisor? An iSCSI LUN? It matters, because you mentioned you made a change to the volume and haven't refreshed the vital details of this volume from within the system. Finally, it's important to know what filesystem is on this volume, so we can advise how to extend it.

Comment: @Michael Hampton Got new physical server disks from Dell and replaced with the old ones.

Comment: @Spooler thanks for the explanation. Yes, I believe it is a RAID array. What do you mean by "filesystem"? How can I find out?

Comment: Can you add the output of the mount command?

Comment: @RoseHosting what command do u mean by that? thank you

Comment: Can anyone help please?..

Comment: We're trying. You have to try as well. The mount command is `mount`. You also have to tell us what RAID array you're using, and what *exactly* you've already done.

Comment: @Spooler Thanks for coming back. It is RAID-5. I have not really done anything else other than replacing the 6 data disks. Literally like took 1 disk out and put 1 new disk for 6 times and made sure each disk finished rebuilding. I will try the mount command and keep this updated.. thanks for help.

Comment: That it's configured as a RAID5 is unimportant to this process, beyond requiring that rebuilds be performed one disk at a time, and verifying rebuild completion after each disk. What I mean to ask is, `what RAID adapter is this system using?` If you're unsure, you can provide the output of `lspci`. It doesn't sound like you've done anything to the RAID abstraction, only the physical members.

Comment: @Spooler I have tried lspci | grep -i raid. The output: 01:00.0 RAID bus controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic MegaRAID SAS 2008 [Falcon] (rev03). Is this what you needed?

Comment: That could be a lot of things. I think you need to look up how to manage RAID on whatever your server hardware is. The problem here is that you're not doing things that need to be done, and expecting it to already be done. You need to update the on-card RAID abstraction to reflect the new capacity of its disk members.